# How to import not confirmed customers via CSV import?

Tags: customer, magento-1, import, csv

I'm trying to import customers via CSV Import:

> `System > Import/Export > Import > Customers > Append Complex Data`

I'd like to import customers which are "not confirmed" after import.

Note: You have to enable the setting `System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Create New Account Options > Require Emails Confirmation` to "Yes" for this to take effect.

The values for the confirmation field in the backend are:

```
<select id="_accountconfirmation" class=" select" name="account[confirmation]">
  <option value="">Confirmed</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="HASH_VALUE">Not confirmed</option>
</select>
```

My CSV includes the confirmation field which I've set to various values (empty, 0, 1, random numbers,...) but the customers are always "confirmed" after the import is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After debugging the import I found out that there is a function `addSystemHiddenFilterWithPasswordHash()` which is called in the `_initAttributes()` method of `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Customer`:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/attribute_collection')->addSystemHiddenFilterWithPasswordHash();
```

The method is defined in `Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Attribute_Collection`:

```
/**
     * Exclude system hidden attributes but include password hash
     *
     * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Attribute_Collection
     */
    public function addSystemHiddenFilterWithPasswordHash()
    {
        $field = '(CASE WHEN additional_table.is_system = 1 AND additional_table.is_visible = 0
            AND main_table.attribute_code != "' . self::EAV_CODE_PASSWORD_HASH . '" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)';
        $this->addFieldToFilter($field, 0);
        return $this;
    }
```

As the `confirmation`field is a system value (see `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/mysql4-data-upgrade-1.4.0.0.7-1.4.0.0.8.php`), you cannot import the information about the confirmation of a customer per default.

So if you ever want to override this, create a rewrite of the `'customer/attribute_collection'` resource model and adapt that method.